# Can I assigm Permission Within an App for PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am pretty new to PowerBI and I was wondering if I can assign users to certain visulaizations within an app. For example: if my dashboard had 3 graphs and each one represent region sales, then head of sales should see all graphs and region manager should see only his/ her graph.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot security trim the display of the visuals and tabs to users, you would have to create separate reports.
What would be better is to deploy the report but to use Row Level Security (RLS) to trim the data. Then in your use case, the head can see all regions, and the regional manager just sees their own.

You'll need a mapping table of people to regions/areas to filer the dataset.
A good place to start is with the [Microsoft overview of RLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls)